# where to find code blocks Sfml image resources

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I'm using code blocks with sfml and besides it looking ugly, I'm not sure where to store images. I have to select the exact path by putting it in the project folder in the file system. How do i add images?

Comment: Yes you need to place the image inside of your project so you can target it via "/Images/Player/Idle.png", you don't need to provide "C:/Users/Jay/etc/etc", could you also provide some code so we can see what you are doing? :)

Comment: To load an image in SFML, you can either give an absolute path, or a relative path, I am guessing you are trying to use the relative one, in which case you have to start the programm from the right folder, else the relative path is modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that your project was in

> C:\Users\Me\Documents\MyProj

Then then putting the images in this folder would make them visible to SFML/codeblocks when using only the image name.

If you had an image called image.png then the full path to the image would be

> C:\Users\Me\Documents\MyProj\image.png

To get the image into your program you must include

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

And create a texture

```
sf::Texture Texture1;
```

And then you can assign this image like

```
 Texture1.loadFromFile("C:\Users\Me\Documents\MyProj\image.png"); //Full path  
 Texture1.loadFromFile("image.png");     //Relative path
```

Next you create a sprite

```
sf::Sprite MySprite
```

And assign the texture to it

```
 MySprite.setTexture(Texture1);
```

Finally to draw in the window use

```
window.draw(MySprite);
```